# sonarqube included header unkown sources

Tags: sonarqube

I have a C++ application that includes foo.h which is provided by a 3rd party tool. foo.h includes bar.h, which I do not have. Is there a way to suppress "cannot find the sources for '# include "bar.h'"?

```
sonar.projectName=MyyAp
sonar.projectBaseDir=src
sonar.sources=.
sonar.cxx.includeDirectories=foo.h,src/includes
```

SonarQube 6.7.1
Sonar-Scanner 3.0.3.778

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `sonar.exclusions=bar.h` ?

**Update**
Just exclude both foo.h and bar.h file as they are provided by 3rd party tool. You can also try `//NOSONAR` tag in the foo.h file

`sonar.exclusions=foo.h, bar.h`

Comment: It didn't work :( It looks like it only ignores sources.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. You can try this one https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/faq/. It says `//NOSONAR` at the end of the line of the issue. This will suppress the all issues - now and in the future - that might be raised on the line.

Comment: It looks like that would require editing the 3rd party library by inserting `//NOSONAR`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes if you are allowed to do it. It will just work as a `//` comment in C++

Comment: Were you able to exclude the files using `//NOSONAR` keyword ?